# Generalization of graph colouring/labeling for regular graphs.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

We call a graph $k$-colourable if there exists a colouring with $k$ colours of the vertices such that adjacent vertices have different colours.
In the case the graph is regular, we can ask whether there exists a colouring with colours $\{1,\dotsc,k\}$ and constants $c_{11},\dotsc,c_{kk}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $c_{ij}$ gives for each vertex with colour $i$ the number of neighbors with colour $j$.

My question is, has this or any comparable type of colouring/labeling been studied, or is this problem equivalent to something else?
I was not successful in finding any literature on this topic.
My goal is to prove that in some special case only the trivial colourings with $k\in\{1,n\}$ are possible, in case this is of any help.